# How to access the dependency version in code?

Tags: java, scala, maven, pom.xml

How can I get the dependency version which I have added in pom from the Java/Scala Code? I don't want to fetch the version of the project, I want to fetch the version of the External Libraries which pom fetches it.

Answer (score 2):

Just type `mvn dependency:tree`
If you want to check a specific external library, do this:
`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]`

If you want to do it on runtime (for example for apache http client):

```
Class<?> clazz = org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.class;
Package p = clazz.getPackage();
System.out.printf("%s%n  Title: %s%n  Version: %s%n",
                      clazz.getName(),
                      p.getImplementationVersion());
```

Comment: I want to fetch it in code. I am writing performance tests and want the metrics to note the version which I am testing. The tests remain same, just the version of library changes with small improvements.

Comment: I tried using `getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` but I don't get the actual version

Comment: @asx This approach (using `HttpClient.class.getPackage()`, not getClass().getPackage()) is the correct way to do it.  However, not all libraries properly define their package attributes;  if that is the case with your version of Apache HttpComponents, there isn’t much you can do.

Comment: @VGR how can I define the package attributes in the pom for the other library?

Comment: @asx I have no idea if Maven has any plugin which can do that.  It requires modifying the manifest of the downloaded .jar file.